# What filter size for Pentax 100SDUF telescope?

Tags: filters

I am looking to use a Pentax 100SDUF telescope as a long focal length lens.  I would like to protect the front element with a clear filter.  There are no markings on the lens as to the size of filter required.  There are some threads at the front of the front lens cell that I can thread onto.  The distance between crests of the treads is 107.1mm measured to the best of my ability.  My best internet searching has not revealed which filter size to which this corresponds.  Since this is a telescope, there is no guarantee that the size of the lens cell actually corresponds to an available filter size.  Since this scope is no longer being produced, there is no one, company wise, that I can ask.

Comment: You’re better off, for both image quality and protection, fashioning a lens hood than using a clear filter.

Comment: Wait, 10.71 *centimeter* thread pitch? Like, almost four and a quarter inches?

Comment: If you really want to use tread-on filters for that lens: use 112mm filters (it's a "common" size and order a custom adapter (yes it would be a metal working piece, it will not be as beautifull as regular ones, and YES it will be not cheap, if you do not know anyone who would do that as an exercise and for a box of beer)

Comment: In this case, a lens cap might actually be the item of choice, if transport protection is the goal :)

Comment: I am interested in using a clear filter for dew protection since this will be out 24/7.  I will be using a dew heater but it is inevitable that dew spots will form.  I know not standard operating procedure but the lens is irreplaceable.  Yes the objective lens is 100mm in size.

Comment: @DerekKuhl Your description in the question could be interpreted to be saying the *thread pitch* (the distance between two adjacent threads at the same angular point on the circle formed by the ring) is 107.1mm, not that the diameter of the opening from one side to the other is 107.1mm.

Comment: @DerekKuhl Lens hoods also offer protection from dew. Standard operating procedure for most backyard astronomers is to use a hood and dew heater (when necessary) while observing and placing an insulating (or even climate controlled) enclosure around the entire rig when not observing, so that temperature changes of the telescope and the air surrounding it are much more gradual.

Comment: @MichaelC I understand the potential confusion about thread pitch. My apologies. The 107.1mm is the diameter across the aperture.

Comment: @MichaelC A lens hood/dew shield is built into the lens/telescope and will assuredly be used. A dew heater will also be used. The rig will be in a roll off roof observatory. None of these safeguards are infallible. I would like to protect the front lens element against the nearly ubiquitous dew spotting I see in this environment.

Comment: I did some measurements on some of my existing lenses. It appears that the measured diameter of the filter threads is typically 0.7 mm less than the quoted filter size. That would mean that this lens would require a 107.8mm filter or thereabouts. I have ordered a 107mm filter off of eBay. We will see if the threads engage or if it will have to be taped/glued on.

Comment: No need to apologize. What you meant was clear. Uncharitable interpretation accompanied by populist outrage is an ordinary behavior on this site.

Comment: A quick google suggests that the telescope was designed so that a Pentax 67 medium format camera could be attached. This and the existence of threads suggests that it was designed to accept a standard filter size. Google suggests the barrel is 114mm in diameter. Both (nominal size) 110mm and 112mm photographic filters appear to be readily available per the internet. 108mm and 114mm do not appear to be ordinary sizes for photographic filters. 110mm would suggest 2mm barrel walls. 112mm suggests 1mm barrel walls.  My 50mm and 24mm photographic lenses have ~1mm barrel walls at the filter threads.

Answer (score 1):

Often the millimeter size of the lens is written on the back of the lens cap.
All of the spotting scopes currently being made by Pentax have the front lens size as part of their model number.  If this applies to your Pentax 100 SDUF, then the filter size should be 100mm.

I went to B&H website (bhphotovideo.com) and discovered that they don't sell a 100mm circular screw-type filter.  Since B&H pretty much carries everything, I assume nobody currently makes a 100mm UV filter. I have found one made by Olympus on eBay for $89. Here's the link https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2334524.m570.l1313.TR0.TRC1.A0.H0.X%22100mm+uv+filter%22.TRS1&_nkw=%22100mm+uv+filter%22&_sacat=625&LH_TitleDesc=0&_osacat=625&_odkw=100mm+uv+filter